# HTML form contains tabs

Tags: java, html, jsp

Is there any way enables me to create html form on a web application which contains tabs like these tabs in the windows without j query?

I want to use only HTML and java code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ul class="list-inline">

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but do you have any idea about what if I want the action not to be href, I want the action when I click this item to show some items to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Use the <s:url> tag to build an action URL:

<s:url value="getCityDetails.action" var="url">
    <s:param name="cityName" value="%{cityName}" />
</s:url>
then use it in a standard <a>:

<a href="<s:property value="%{#url}"/>">
    <s:property value="cityName" />
</a>
or in an <s:a>:

<s:a href="%{url}">
    <s:property value="cityName" />
</s:a>
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this:

this comes from [this webpage](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-tabs-using-target-selector/) and uses CSS3 and HTML5 for the whole deal

```
< head>

  < style>
    article.tabs{
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 40em;
      height: 15em;
      margin: 2em auto;
    }
article.tabs section{
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 1.8em;
left: 0;
height: 12em;
padding: 10px 20px;
background-color: #ddd;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
z-index: 0;
 }

article.tabs section:first-child
{
    z-index: 1;
}

article.tabs section h2
{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 120px;
    height: 1.8em;
    top: -1.8em;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #999;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

article.tabs section:nth-child(2) h2
{
    left: 132px;
}

article.tabs section:nth-child(3) h2
{
    left: 254px;
}

article.tabs section h2 a
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    outline: 0 none;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>....
<article class="tabs">

    <section id="tab1">
        <h2><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on tab 1.</p>
    </section>

    <section id="tab2">
        <h2><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on tab 2.</p>
    </section>

    <section id="tab3">
        <h2><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on tab 3.</p>
    </section>

</article>
</body>
```